# Cannot create a user with an empty login name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site `mysite.com` and a subdomain `mysite.com/subdomain`. I need to copy users from `mysite.com/subdomain` to `mysite.com`. I tried

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (<fields>) SELECT <fields> FROM subdomain_users
```

wp_users fields are `user_login`, `user_email` and `user_registered` and then let them all to reset their password.

everything works fine but there are two problems:

- when the administrator wants to edit users profile or users want to edit their profile face this error: `Cannot create a user with an empty login name.`
- the text and visual tab in wp tinymce editor are hidden for these users when adding posts. but if I add new user as usual users>>Add new then they can see the visual and text tabs.

Any advice and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by Exporting all the user and user data from your subdomain site and import all those to your main site. You can take help of the Plugin :

[Cimy User Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-manager/)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Tristup. My Subdomain site is not Wordpress. this plugin needs the subdomain site to be in Wordpress?

Comment: Ok, then you can export the users from your user database [ if you have the access ] in csv format, and import the same in main site with the plugin. That will work

Comment: If you dont have the access, then you need to write a program to export those data from database to a CSV formatted file which can be uploaded.

Comment: Thank you. I have access. I will try the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Login is required to connect to the server, once login is created, that login will have right to connect to the server. But access to the databases present on that server will only possible when you create a user but it must be mapped to some login. For example as below

```
CREATE LOGIN test WITH PASSWORD=N'test', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF

CREATE USER test_user FOR LOGIN test WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Your error says, you have created user but it is not mapped to any login.